# where can I find Treemaker Related documentation in tools.jar

Tags: java

where can I find Treemaker related documentation in tools.jar
I want to learn some usage
I had searched on google,but I can not find some useful documentation

when I write some samples,occur some error,code following:

```
  private JCTree.JCMethodDecl makeListMethodDecl(){
    JCTree.JCMethodDecl method = maker.MethodDef(
            maker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC | Flags.STATIC),
            names.fromString("getStrings"),
            maker.Type(new Type.JCVoidType()),
            List.nil(),
            List.nil(),
            List.nil(),
            maker.Block(
                    0,
                    List.of(maker.Return(
                            maker.NewClass(
                                    null,
                                    List.nil(),
                                    maker.TypeApply(
                                            maker.Ident(names.fromString("java.util.List")),
                                            List.of(maker.Ident(names.fromString("java.lang.String")))
                                    ),
                                    List.nil(),
                                    null
                            )
                    ))
            ),
            null
    );
    return method;
}
```

I dont know where it is wrong

Comment: If you can't find it with Google, there is a good chance that it doesn't exist (apart from Oracle corporate networks, etc).

Comment: However I did find this (non-Oracle) paper - https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7b0f/c89f3bfdd7521d24bff6b555bc02dccb8914.pdf

Comment: thanks,I pasted my code above.